# What would you think what "deal dividend" would mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/uks-brexit-deal-worse-continued-000100390.html) (I am sorry I am asking tons of Brexit questions since I decided I will throw all the money into the U.K pound) and the 7th passage says,

> "We don't expect there to be a **'deal dividend'** at all," NIESR economist Arno Hantzsche said. "A deal would reduce the risk of a disorderly Brexit outcome but eliminate the possibility of a closer economic relationship."

I personally think the term dividend here is used by the definition of 1 a or b, which are,

> 1 a :  an individual share of something distributed among a number of recipients
>
> b :  a share in a pro rata distribution (as of profits) to stockholders
>
> c :  a share of surplus allocated to a policyholder in a participating insurance policy generally representing a return of a portion of the premium not needed to meet losses and expenses and a distribution of earnings from investment
>
> d :  a bonus item given to a customer with each purchase of a set number of items
>
> e :  the return or reward resulting from an activity, effort, or undertaking
>
> f :  something received unexpectedly or in addition to that which is usual or that which is expected or sought :  bonus
>
> g :  a portion of a mixed iced drink remaining after the regular servings have been poured out
>
> 2
>   [Anglo-French dividende, from Latin dividendum]
>   a obsolete :  the act or an instance of dividing (as profits or spoils) among a number of individuals
>
> b :  a pro rata distribution of money, securities, or other property; especially :  such a distribution to corporate shareholders or to creditors of a bankrupt estate — see stock dividend
>
> 3
>   mathematics :  a number or quantity to be divided
>
> 4
>   archaic :  a body of land in one patent or survey

But I get the meaning very vaguely or almost nothing.

My question is,

1 Is my understanding (dictionary definition) correct?

2 What would this phrase mean in a context?

Thank you(m_m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means here is "an increase in real wealth" that can be shared. In other words, it is sense e.